# How many basic rotations do I need to make any rotation in $n$ dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that I want to make some rotation in $n$-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n$. I can construct a basic rotation $R_{ij}$ in some plane spanned by two basis vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$. Then I obviously can construct any rotation by multiplying all $R_{ij}$ matrices. But there are $C^2_n$ such matrices, and it seems too much.

Do I really need all basic rotation matrices to make any rotation? And if not, then how many and which of them do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to construct an **arbitrary** rotation out of **only** basic rotations, then you generally need all $^2C_n$ of them. But of course there can be rotations for which you don't need to use all basic rotations.

As an analogy, do you need to take the linear combination of all the basis vectors to form a vector in a vector space? Obviously for basis vectors or vectors lying in subspaces, you don't need to do that. But for general, arbitary vectors, you may need all basis vectors to express them.

In short, depends on the rotation that you're considering.

Comment: This is not immediately obvious to me (for example, you can generate all basic rotations by an angle of $\pi/2$ using only $n-1$ basic rotations). Is there an easy proof?